# REALLY customizing Views in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, module, view, customization

Every time I see people talk about customizing the views module for Drupal, they just move some text around, change the font, etc. How do I, for example, put each views item on a png pic of a slice of bread with peanut butter & jelly on it? I wanna customize what the content is sitting on.

Answer (score 0):

You can override views output with template files. These new template files should reside in your current theme folder and need to have a specific name.

Edit your view, then expand the right (advanced) column and at the bottom choose `Theme: information`. It will provide you a list of possible template files to alter exactly what you need; fields, rows or the entire output.

Click the type to get the original template code and then copy that code to a new file (suggestions are given) and place the file in your theme folder. Then hit the update button in the Views theme dialog. It should find the newly created file.

From there, go nuts with HTML and CSS